# Ant path (pointer end)

Tags: logic, vectors, contest-math, physics

**We consider a wall clock that has a pointer in Seconds. A little ant part of the pointer axis and moves to the other end, always just as quickly. Sketch the ant's trajectory relative to the watch face**

Wanted in trajectory with respect to the watch face and the ant of the clock, the ant was on the pointer in seconds in 60s the ant was turning the clock completely and she was walking in rectilinear motion. But regarding the ant she was doing rectilinear movement.

And as for the dial I don't know ... I think it's curvilinear movement. I was also in doubt of simple cycloid

Comment: Tags seem off...

Comment: This is called Archimedean spiral. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral